# How does the lambda expression work in Program.cs file of Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, asp.net-core, delegates

I am learning to build web pages using Razor pages (.NET Core 2.0) and I am fairly new to C# itself. So, I went through this piece of code:

```
public class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .Build();
}
```

I cannot understand the usage of lambda expression here ? How is this an anonymous function or a delegate ? I have looked for answers but failed. can anyone help me understand this ?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

Comment: In a few words, if your method has only one line you can use `=>` instead of an open/close bracket, that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: This isn't a lambda, it's an 'expression-bodied method' -- a new short syntax for the methods that have only a return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's one line code so we can use the `=>`

It's the same as :

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) 
{
    return WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome! For more details about Lambda expression in C# this documentation might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions